# .net core best practice on where to save JSON schema file

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-core-2.0, jsonschema

I am generating a Json schema file in .net core 2 and I was wondering which one of the following is the best way to go when saving the schema for future use (e.g. validation and deserialisation):

- save it to wwwroot, but in this case wouldn't it be available on client side (which I don't like)?
- save it to a specifically-built db as a string. In this case, the db would be of two columns (the id and the string) and one row (the schema).
- saving it in the appsettings.json (if it makes sense).

Which one do you think it is better?

Comment: ... just a question; why do you want JSON schema validation?

Comment: As in general; if your schema contains information for your users, you should make it public accessible. If it's for unit testing you  should keep it internally.

Comment: You can also save it somewhere in the ContentRoot and add functionality to read or expose the contents in the way you want.